# Image with Entry and having a circular border

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

[image]Is there any way to place a image with Entry and having a circular border.
Till now succeeded with circular border using custom EntryRenderer. But not able to put image inside that border.

```
 public class ExtendedEntryRender : EntryRenderer{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
        {
            GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(252, 247, 191, 178));
            gd.SetCornerRadius(30);
            gd.SetStroke(1, Android.Graphics.Color.Argb(252, 247, 191, 178));
            this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
            this.Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            this.Control.SetCursorVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: post what you tried in question

Comment: @Rahul  Have created GradientDrawable in OnElementChanged() in ExtendedEntryRender class

Comment: please post in question

Comment: @rahul  edited the post

Comment: also it will be good if you post what result you are getting and what you are expecting in form of images.

Comment: @Rahul -above is the image what I actually want but not able to get inside left image .

Answer (score 0):

If I was going to attempt something like this. I probably would have started with the XLabs Circle Image Control.
Followed by Something similar to what you have and then put them both inside the same cell of a Grid Control to get them to stack on top of each other.